# PDF is not Generating in Live Server (Windows 2008 R2 enterprise) with wkhtmltopdf.exe, but works in Local Host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wkhtmltopdf

We are using `wkhtmltopdf.exe` (up to 10 months it had been worked with no issues) but from few days we are facing issue with `wkhtmltopdf.exe`. For now we are getting error from `wkhtmltopdf.exe` and PDF is not generating for us, we use JavaScripts. When I click page is going to our written error page. Our problem in PDF is not coming with any versions from `wkhtmltopdf.exe`. Our code and applications are very clear .`wkhtmltopdf.exe` is working in local why not in live server(Windows 2008 R2 enterprise)? We had tried all the versions from (wkhtmltopdf site)[http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html] all were worked in localhost but not in live server this tool is very important in our product looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use the ASP.NET development server locally (Cassini, basically IIS6), and on your windows server, you have IIS 7+. Your ASP.NET application pool is probably in integrated mode security (on IIS7+), and you can't call external programs from there (you can in IIS6 mode - classic mode in IIS7), let alone access paths outside the web application root folder.

You can try incorporating wkHtmlToPdfSharp as DLL. 
I have here:
https://github.com/ststeiger/wkHtmlToPdfSharp

it's a minor revision from Pechkin project here 
https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin

or you can try switching the application pool to classic mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply in our local server iis version is (7.5) is same as in live server is about iis version(7.5).

Comment: Thanks for your reply in our local server iis version is (7.5) is same as in live server is about iis version(7.5) what to do next ?? in localhost pdf is generating with iis version is (7.5) having same version in Windows 2008 R2 enterprise but PDF is not generating.

Comment: Thanks for your reply in our local server iis version is (7.5) is same as in live server is about iis version(7.5) what to do next ?? in localhost pdf is generating with iis version is (7.5) having same version in Windows 2008 R2 enterprise but PDF is not generating - @Quandary

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of wkhtmltopdf you are using? I've got exactly the same problem, my version is 0.12.3.

After 3 days struggling with this issue, I found that for whtmltopdf software to generate pdf, we need 2 file msvcp120.dll & msvrp120.dll to running from server side. After I copied these 2 files into the same folder as the wkhtmltopdf.exe. It works perfectly. Hope this helps.